# how to turn data of years to 5-year intervals in boxplot in R?

Tags: r, intervals, boxplot

I have data called females with two variables (timeresponse, age). I wanted to draw a boxplot of their time response based on their age in 5-year intervals. I would be thankful if you'd help out.

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Apart form that, please have a look at the `cut` function which offers to split your time response into equal intervals. Howwver, if `cut` works will also depend on the data type of your input variables (i.e. are these numeric values or datetime objects?).

Comment: What have you tried so far Sara?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not given any sample data, let's first create one

```
library(tidyverse)
  

set.seed(50)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:1000,
                 dates = as.Date("1990-01-01") + runif(1000)*10000,
                 measure = runif(1000)*50)

> (tibble(df))
# A tibble: 1,000 x 3
      id dates      measure
   <int> <date>       <dbl>
 1     1 2009-05-28    27.0
 2     2 2001-12-25    26.1
 3     3 1995-06-24    18.6
 4     4 2011-01-01    26.3
 5     5 2004-01-19    17.1
 6     6 1991-03-24    22.5
 7     7 2009-03-01    19.2
 8     8 2007-09-12    32.5
 9     9 1991-02-25    24.6
10    10 1992-12-11    33.9
```

You can use `cut()` function to group dates.  the sample code may be

```
df %>% mutate(dategroup = cut(dates, breaks = "5 years")) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=dategroup, y=measure, color = dategroup))
```

Boxplot generated

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Well, I am quite new to R and couldn't figure out how to deal with my data. I am using nym.2002 data in the UsingR package. This is what I tried:  


`mutate(nym.2002, dategroup = cut(nym2002 $ age, breaks == 5 )) %>% ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=dategroup, y=nym2002 $ time, color = dategroup))`

Comment: Please accept and upvote, if it helped, as usually desired on SO.  :)